# Are there nonempty sets that are their own binary Cartesian product?

Tags: set-theory, universal-algebra

The empty set being the trivial example of a set that is its own Cartesian power, I want to know:

Are there nonempty sets that are their own binary Cartesian product?

Comment: You have really asked two completely different questions here whose answers are totally unrelated (your main question and the question in your last paragraph).  I would suggest asking them in separate posts.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the usual Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs, this is impossible by the axiom of regularity.  Note that the rank of the ordered pair $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ is greater than the ranks of both $x$ and $y$ (specifically, it is $\max(\operatorname{rank}(x),\operatorname{rank}(y))+2$).  So if $X$ is a nonempty set and $x\in X$ is an element of minimal rank, every element of $X\times X$ has rank greater than the rank of $x$.  In particular, $x\not\in X\times X$, so $X\neq X\times X$.

If you don't assume the axiom of regularity, then it is consistent for there to be nonempty sets $X$ such that $X=X\times X$.  For instance, it is consistent for there to exist a set $X$ such that $X=\{X\}$, and so then $$X\times X=\{(X,X)\}=\{\{\{X\}\}\}=\{\{X\}\}=\{X\}=X.$$

Comment: Interestingly, there does exist $X$ with $\phi\ne X\supset X\times X.$ For example if $X=H_{\omega},$  the set of hereditarily finite well-founded sets.